# Iperf under Cygwin not recognizing arguments

Tags: windows, cygwin, iperf

I'm running Cygwin on Windows 7 and trying to run Iperf 2.0.5-2 with it. For some reason, any arguments passed to it seem to be ignored. For example,

```
./iperf.exe --help
```

or

```
./iperf.exe -s
```

simply output usage instructions. (Same as the output from running iperf.exe with no arguments.) Other applications have no problem accepting input arguments. To be honest I have no idea where to start.. Has anyone seen this before? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I just recently had the same problem.
I downloaded iperf & cygwin and none of the iperf commands worked in the cygwin terminal.

I eventually realized though that you didn't need cygwin to run iperf on windows.

All you have to do if extract the iperf.zip into a folder of your choosing.
Open up command prompt and CD to the folder.
Type any command. For example:

```
iperf -s
```

and it should be running now.